# What happens to child objects after a standard Account Matching Rule?

Tags: merge

I have 20 duplicate accounts.

After merging 3 of them, all the children of these 20 accounts have been attached to only one of the merged accounts.

I precise that standart duplicate and matching rule have been applied to the 3 accounts.

Is this standard behaviour or is it the cause of some custom code?

Comment: How did you merge them

Comment: Standart duplicate and matching have been user for these account @identigral